# Korbit exchange access and currency support

Tags: exchange, fiat

According to this recent [blog post](http://blog.naver.com/korbitinc/220879588892) Korbit, [Korea's largest Bitcoin exchange](http://www.theverge.com/2014/1/19/5325636/korbit-korea-bitcoin-exchange-400000-silicon-valley-investment) now supports Monero(XMR) trading.

> This Multi-Trading Service supports trading of more various digital assets other than just Bitcoin, Ethereum and Ethereum Classic, which are already supported by Korbit. Therefore, if you are a level 3 or higher member of Korbit, you can take advantage of the service without the hassle of using a foreign service to do buy and sell digital assets.

What is the definition of [level 3](http://korbitblog.tumblr.com/post/154118056383/%EA%B3%B5%EC%A7%80-%EB%A9%80%ED%8B%B0%ED%8A%B8%EB%A0%88%EC%9D%B4%EB%94%A9-%EB%9F%B0%EC%B9%AD-%EC%95%88%EB%82%B4multi-trading-launching)? Are you required to be a Korean citizen to use [Korbit](https://www.korbit.co.kr/)? What fiat currencies are supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used the exchange, but with some google fu I've managed to piece together the following:

You need a [Korean bank account](https://www.reddit.com/r/xmrtrader/comments/5gwc27/korbit_adds_xmr/davmep9/), in your name, to use Korbit.

[Level 3](http://korbitblog.tumblr.com/post/154118056383/%EA%B3%B5%EC%A7%80-%EB%A9%80%ED%8B%B0%ED%8A%B8%EB%A0%88%EC%9D%B4%EB%94%A9-%EB%9F%B0%EC%B9%AD-%EC%95%88%EB%82%B4multi-trading-launching) means you've verified your account by sending in a scan of your diver's license or equivalent.

If you browse the [Korbit](https://www.korbit.co.kr/) site you see that the only fiat that is supported, for the listed pairs, is the South Korean Won.  It's a reasonable guess that the same is true to for the currencies that are available upon verification.